# how do I make each row of a Numpy array be evenly aligned with the rows below

Tags: python, numpy

so I'm trying to make a sudoku program and I keep getting annoyed because my data doesn't come out neat and organized. I'm using python numpy arrays and printing them to get the data

my data looks like this

```
[[6 5 3 189 7 2 4 89 189]
 [1789 1789 89 135689 3569 4 56789 2 136789]
 [1789 4 2 135689 3569 3569 56789 356789 136789]
 [2 369 7 3569 4 8 569 1 369]
 [13589 13689 4 3569 2 35679 56789 356789 36789]
 [3589 3689 5689 3569 1 35679 2 356789 4]
 [5789 6789 1 2 5689 569 3 4 6789]
 [35789 36789 5689 4 5689 1569 16789 6789 2]
 [4 2 689 7 3689 1369 1689 689 5]]
```

I want it to look more spaced out and even with the values below so I can read it easier

Comment: Find some libraries for data representing

Comment: Doesn't look at all like numpy's display tho

Comment: What's the `dtype`?

Comment: @chrslg Agreed. OP, the numpy printout would be spaced so that each column is right justified and lines up with the one below.

Comment: @jared, it must be an object dtype array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I copy-n-paste several lines of your display, and remove the brackets, I can get some lines of text:

```
txt="""6 5 3 189 7 2 4 89 189
 1789 1789 89 135689 3569 4 56789 2 136789
 1789 4 2 135689 3569 3569 56789 356789 136789"""

txt.splitlines()
Out[44]: 
['6 5 3 189 7 2 4 89 189',
 ' 1789 1789 89 135689 3569 4 56789 2 136789',
 ' 1789 4 2 135689 3569 3569 56789 356789 136789']
```

From that I can load it (as though from csv file):

```
data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=int)
```

The repr display of that array is:

```
data
Out[46]: 
array([[     6,      5,      3,    189,      7,      2,      4,     89,
           189],
       [  1789,   1789,     89, 135689,   3569,      4,  56789,      2,
        136789],
       [  1789,      4,      2, 135689,   3569,   3569,  56789, 356789,
        136789]])
```

and the print display looks like yours - except the columns are lined up. That's the normal numpy print:

```
print(data)
[[     6      5      3    189      7      2      4     89    189]
 [  1789   1789     89 135689   3569      4  56789      2 136789]
 [  1789      4      2 135689   3569   3569  56789 356789 136789]]
```

I'm not sure what you printed.  It's not lined up, but it doesn't have commas.

The list display doesn't line up, but has commas:

```
In [48]: data.tolist()
Out[48]: 
[[6, 5, 3, 189, 7, 2, 4, 89, 189],
 [1789, 1789, 89, 135689, 3569, 4, 56789, 2, 136789],
 [1789, 4, 2, 135689, 3569, 3569, 56789, 356789, 136789]]
```

lets cast it to objec dtype:

```
print(data.astype(object))
[[6 5 3 189 7 2 4 89 189]
 [1789 1789 89 135689 3569 4 56789 2 136789]
 [1789 4 2 135689 3569 3569 56789 356789 136789]]
```

and back to int

```
print(data.astype(object).astype(int))
[[     6      5      3    189      7      2      4     89    189]
 [  1789   1789     89 135689   3569      4  56789      2 136789]
 [  1789      4      2 135689   3569   3569  56789 356789 136789]]
```

So that's your problem, it is object dtype, which is list like.  You need to make it int (or float) if you want it to lineup.